# How to upload an image using NodeJS, Nginx and base64? (413 PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large)

Tags: node.js, nginx, base64, image-uploading, payload

I am trying to upload 5 base64 images using Postman raw text option, with application/json header set.
The server keeps returning the error mentioned.
I am using NodeJS behind Nginx reverse proxy.

I have tried all of the options mentioned in the code below, including increasing the limits up to (100M), which apparently wasn't the issue.

NodeJS (MAXIMUM_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT='500mb'):

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: process.env.MAXIMUM_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT, parameterLimit: 100000, extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: process.env.MAXIMUM_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT, extended: true }));
// app.use(bodyParser.text({ limit: process.env.MAXIMUM_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT, extended:true }));
app.use( bodyParser.text({type : 'application/text-enriched', limit: process.env.MAXIMUM_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT}) );   
app.use( bodyParser.raw({limit: process.env.MAXIMUM_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT}) );
```

Nginx
Configuration inside (server, http, location):
nginx.conf,
sites-enabled/default,
sites-available/default:

```
client_max_body_size 100M
```

I want to succeed uploading the images (5), which their total size is not more than 2MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution finally was to leave the nginx's `client_max_body_size 5M;` only at the `nginx.conf`, as-well as using the following lines in my NodeJS code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '5mb', extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '5mb' }));
```

**PLEASE NOTE!!!**
After trying a lot of combinations the problem appeared to be unrelated to the metnioned above, at all.
While using the `node` command in-order to execute the server, everything worked great. But, because I wanted to keep the application alive (in-case of a server reboot), I have used `forever`.
Forever started the application, but apparently kept throwing the `413` error everytime, regardless of nginx's and node's settings.
Switched to `PM2`, which finally solved that.

Good luck!